# How to change count dynamically after filters in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, datatable, laravel-8

I have stats section where I want to show the count of records in datatable, there is filtering option after which datatable records get filteredout, I want to show stats section should update as the data table is filtered. For e.g. if Datatable shows 100 records the count in stats should be 100, if 8 records filtered the the stats should change dynamically to 8. Is there a way how I can do that. Currently I am able to get the count but it's not changing after applying filters.

This is my Controller code:

```
  public function index(Request $request,ExportDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            if(!empty($request->BusinessUnit) || !empty($request->CurrOrg1)  || !empty($request->CurrOrg2)  || !empty($request->Role)  || !empty($request->Region)  || !empty($request->ProfessionalClassification)  || !empty($request->Gender)  || !empty($request->CurrOrg3)  || !empty($request->CurrOrg4)  || !empty($request->CurrOrg5))
            {             
                $loged_user =Auth::user();
                $user= DB:: table('users')
                    ->selectRaw('users.*, REPLACE(Org2, "Admin", "") AS ROrg2, REPLACE(Org1, "Admin", "") AS ROrg1, REPLACE(Org3, "Admin" , "") AS ROrg3')
                    ->where('email',$loged_user->email)
                    ->first();
                $query= DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->select('predictions.id','predictions.EmployeeNumber','predictions.Role','predictions.Region','predictions.CurrOrg1','predictions.CurrOrg2','predictions.RiskZone','predictions.Probablity','predictions.Rating','predictions.Feedback','predictions.Gender','predictions.CurrOrg3','predictions.CurrOrg4','predictions.CurrOrg5','predictions.ProfessionalClassification','predictions.Local_Expat','predictions.EmployeeRoleSeniority','predictions.FeedRisklevel','predictions.Feedinfluencers','predictions.Action','predictions.Fname','predictions.Lname','predictions.Avgweekhr');
                if(!empty($request->CurrOrg2)) {
                    $query->whereIn('CurrOrg2',$request->CurrOrg2);
                }

                if(!empty($request->Region)) {
                     $query->whereIn('Region',$request->Region);
                }

                if(!empty($request->ProfessionalClassification)) {
                     $query->whereIn('ProfessionalClassification',$request->ProfessionalClassification);
                }
                if(!empty($request->CurrOrg1)) {
                    $query->whereIn('CurrOrg1',$request->CurrOrg1);
                }
                if(!empty($request->CurrOrg3)) {
                     $query->whereIn('CurrOrg3',$request->CurrOrg3);
                }
                if(!empty($request->CurrOrg4)) {
                     $query->whereIn('CurrOrg4',$request->CurrOrg4);
                }
                if(!empty($request->CurrOrg5)) {
                     $query->whereIn('CurrOrg5',$request->CurrOrg5);
                }
                if(!empty($request->Role)) {
                    $query->whereIn('Role',$request->Role);
                }
                if(!empty($request->BusinessUnit)) {
                    $query->whereIn('BusinessUnit',$request->BusinessUnit);
                }
                if(!empty($request->Gender)) {
                     $query->whereIn('Gender',$request->Gender);
                }
                $data = $query->get();    
            }       
            else
            {
                $loged_user =Auth::user();
                $user= DB:: table('users')
                    ->selectRaw('users.*, REPLACE(Org2, "Admin", "") AS ROrg2, REPLACE(Org1, "Admin", "") AS ROrg1, REPLACE(Org3, "Admin" , "") AS ROrg3')
                    ->where('email',$loged_user->email)
                    ->first();
                $data1 =DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->select('predictions.id','predictions.EmployeeNumber','predictions.Role','predictions.Region','predictions.CurrOrg1','predictions.CurrOrg2','predictions.RiskZone','predictions.Probablity','predictions.Rating','predictions.Feedback','predictions.Gender','predictions.CurrOrg3','predictions.CurrOrg4','predictions.CurrOrg5','predictions.ProfessionalClassification','predictions.Local_Expat','predictions.EmployeeRoleSeniority','predictions.FeedRisklevel','predictions.Feedinfluencers','predictions.Action','predictions.Fname','predictions.Lname','predictions.Avgweekhr');  
                $data = $data1->get();     
                }
                
       
            return datatables()->of($data)
            ->addColumn('Feedback', function($data)
            {   
                if($data->Action == 'No')
                {
                return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#CA0088;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                }
                else
                   {
                     return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#00A300;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                   } 
            })
            ->escapeColumns([])
            ->make(true);
        }
        $Business_unit_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('BusinessUnit')
                            ->groupBy('BusinessUnit')
                            ->orderBy('BusinessUnit', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $CurrOrg1_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg1')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg1')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg1', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $CurrOrg2_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg2')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg2')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg2', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $CurrOrg3_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg3')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg3')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg3', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $CurrOrg4_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg4')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg4')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg4', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $CurrOrg5_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg5')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg5')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg5', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Role_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('Role')
                            ->groupBy('Role')
                            ->orderBy('Role', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Region_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('Region')
                            ->groupBy('Region')
                            ->orderBy('Region', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Gender_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('Gender')
                            ->groupBy('Gender')
                            ->orderBy('Gender', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $ProfessionalClassification_name = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('ProfessionalClassification')
                            ->groupBy('ProfessionalClassification')
                            ->orderBy('ProfessionalClassification', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Prediction= new Prediction;
        $Prediction_list= $Prediction::all();
        $Topcorrelators = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('Topcorrelators')
                            ->groupBy('Topcorrelators')
                            ->orderBy('Topcorrelators', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $loged_user =Auth::user();
        $user= DB:: table('users')
                    ->selectRaw('users.*, REPLACE(Org2, "Admin", "") AS ROrg2, REPLACE(Org1, "Admin", "") AS ROrg1, REPLACE(Org3, "Admin" , "") AS ROrg3')
                    ->where('email',$loged_user->email)
                    ->first();
        $Highrisk= DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->where('RiskZone','High Risk')
                        ->count();
        $Lowrisk= DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->where('RiskZone','Low Risk')
                        ->count();
        $Records= DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->count();                        
        $Action= DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->where('CurrOrg1','like','%'.$user->ROrg1.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg2','like','%'.$user->ROrg2.'%')
                        ->where('CurrOrg3','like','%'.$user->ROrg3.'%')
                        ->where('Action','!=','No')
                        ->count();
        return view('admin.members.Predictions', compact('Business_unit_name','CurrOrg1_name','CurrOrg2_name','CurrOrg3_name','CurrOrg4_name','CurrOrg5_name','Role_name','Region_name','Gender_name','Topcorrelators','ProfessionalClassification_name','Prediction_list','Highrisk','Lowrisk','Records','Action'));
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Info boxes -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="info-box">
              <span class="info-box-icon bg-info elevation-1"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></span>

              <div class="info-box-content">
                <span class="info-box-text"># Employees</span>
                <span class="info-box-number">
                 {{ $Records }}
                </span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.info-box-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.info-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="info-box mb-3">
              <span class="info-box-icon bg-danger elevation-1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>

              <div class="info-box-content">
                <span class="info-box-text">High Risk Employees</span>
                <span class="info-box-number"> {{ $Highrisk }} </span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.info-box-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.info-box -->
          </div>
```

If it is possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hi If your all records in data variable so simply you can check count in laravel blade
for example **{{ count($data) }}**

or
you can get data with paginate and
use **{{ $data->total() }}**

Thanks.

Comment: It gives error that $data is not defined when I am trying to use it in Blade file

Comment: You are not sending the $data var from the controller to the view,

Comment: How to send that? because when I am trying to send in view it is still giving error maybe coz it is out of scope

Comment: Can you please help me out how I can send $data to view?

Comment: return datatables()->of($data)->addColumn('Feedback', function($data)
            {   
                if($data->Action == 'No')
                {
                return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#CA0088;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                }
                else
                   {
                     return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#00A300;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                   } 
            })->with($data)->escapeColumns([])->make(true);

Comment: Still giving same error

Comment: $data is undifined is error I am getting when trying to get count in view

Comment: data = 'foobar';
return datatables()
       ->of($query)
       ->addColumn('Action', function() use ($data){
           return view('Actions.something', compact('data'));
       })
       ->rawColumns(['Action'])
       ->toJson();

can you check to apply this

Comment: it's giving datatable error